# Maven keeps overwriting my spring boot application.properties file?

Tags: maven, spring-boot, config, application.properties

I am using the open source messenger4j project to create a spring boog based Facebook bot:

```
https://github.com/messenger4j/messenger4j-spring-boot-quickstart-template
```

I am running on Ubuntu 12.x and using Maven 3.5.0.

I need to use nano to edit the application.properties file of the Maven project. I make my edits, which include changing the server port and a few other SSL related items and the application.properties file looks like this:

```
messenger4j.appSecret = ${MESSENGER_APP_SECRET}
messenger4j.verifyToken = ${MESSENGER_VERIFY_TOKEN}
messenger4j.pageAccessToken = ${MESSENGER_PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN}
logging.level.com.github.messenger4j=INFO
server.port=1919
... <other edits> ...
```

I then save the file, exit nano, and "cat" that file to make sure the edits are still there. They are. However, when I compile and run the messenger4j app with this maven wrapper command line:

```
./mvnw spring-boot:run
```

I notice that the status messages tell me that the embedded Tomcat server is not listening on port 1919 but instead on the default port 8080. I reopen the application.properties file and I see only the default content again and see this:

```
messenger4j.appSecret = ${MESSENGER_APP_SECRET}
messenger4j.verifyToken = ${MESSENGER_VERIFY_TOKEN}
messenger4j.pageAccessToken = ${MESSENGER_PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN}
logging.level.com.github.messenger4j=INFO
```

Does anyone know what is causing this and how to fix this?  It appears that Maven is overwriting the application.properties file from some other source each time it compiles and runs (I'm guessing here)?

I saw a stack overflow post talking about a command line flag that tells maven not to overwrite the application.properties file. But if there is another source file that Maven is using (or should use) to auto-generate the application.properties file, I would like to edit that file instead of using that flag and stay with the usual expected workflow of a Maven project.  I also would rather not pass a boat load of parameters on the mvnw command line either if I can help it.

**UPDATE**: Added pom.xml file.

Here is my **pom.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.github.messenger4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>messenger4j-spring-boot-quickstart-template</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>${project.groupId}:${project.artifactId}</name>
    <description>Facebook Messenger Chatbot Template using Java, Spring Boot, and messenger4j</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.messenger4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>messenger4j</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

UPDATE: It turns out I was editing the **./target/classes/application.properties** file instead of the file that Maven copies from to create that file.  I'm referring to the *true* source file named **./src/main/resources/application.properties**.  Thank you *dunni* & *Kyle*.

Comment: Please format the post correctly...

Comment: What is the exact path of the application.properties file, which you are editing?

Comment: @dunni The path is is ./src/main/resources/application.properties.  There is another file in ./target/classes/application.properties, but that didn't exist until the first time I ran Maven so I assumed it was an auto-generated file.

Comment: Can you post the content of your pom.xml?

Comment: @RobertOschler The application.properties file within ./target isn't auto-generated.  It is merely copied over from ./src  As dunni has asked, please share your pom.xml  By default there isn't any plugin that would overwrite the application.properties file, unless you've added something else to your pom.xml

Comment: @dunni I added the pom.xml file.  See my original post.

Comment: @KyleAnderson - Just added it.

Comment: Hey Robert, please take a look at the build log. As Kyle said, the `application.properties` is copied from `src/main/resources` as part of the build process.
Hold on, are you sure you are editing the file in `src/main/resources` and not the one in `target/` right?

Comment: I would also suggest you check the plugin docs, sometimes they autogenerate some files (or use the default config) if they can't find them, and you need to specifically add a line to avoid the autogeneration.

Comment: @germanio That did it.  You're right.  I had created a shell script to edit the application.properties file to save on typing and I accidentally put the ./target sourced version instead of the ./src version.  Thanks.

Comment: @germanio Funny you mention that.  I'm facing a very similar problem in another project that uses Gradle instead of Maven.  Some  plug-in keeps rewriting certain files and since I'm new to IntelliJ/Gradle, I haven't figured out what it is yet.  Any general tips on tracking down "shadow behavior" of a plugin?  The project is using quite a few of them.  I inherited the project from another dev so I'm not familiar with them.

Comment: Nice to hear that you fixed it!
Regarding the plugins in Gradle/Maven, you can probably set the log level to `debug` and try to see if the source and target dirs are logged.